# login and logout in swing

Tags: java, swing

I have made a form containing username and password...and submit button
So after clicking on submit...I have to do validation part in separate program, Which on getting result as true will allow user to navigate to inner homepage...add disable login page.And if login details are wrong it will show message dialog..showing wrong username and password..

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if (ae.getSource() == submit) 
    {
        //to do...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's all nice, but what's your question?

Comment: what will be the coding..that i need to be done on submit button

Comment: That depends.  How are you validating the user?  I can suggest you take a look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) which will allow to perform the process in a background thread though

Comment: do not comment if u have nt understand the requirement....

Comment: How are we suppose to garnish the information we need to help you if you don't 1- ask an appropriate question or 2- are unwilling to fill the gaps of our understanding?

Comment: how much appropiation u need..??

Comment: try some registration , store username password in DB and fetch the username password in login form , like everyone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing how the user details are validated, its safe to say that you won't want to be calling it within the context of the EDT.

Instead, I've used a `SwingWorker` to do the work for me (you'll have to fill that in).  It simply returns a `true` or `false` value back to the EDT.

If the login in failed, we simply show a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) showing a "Failed login" message.  Otherwise we can simply dispose of the login dialog...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLogin();
    }

    public TestLogin() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JDialog frame = new JDialog((Frame) null, "Login", true);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            add(new JLabel("User Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Password:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JPasswordField(10), gbc);

            JButton okay = new JButton("Okay");
            JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(okay, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(cancel, gbc);

            okay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setFormEnabled(false);
                    new LoginWorker().execute();
                }
            });

            cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.windowForComponent((Component) e.getSource()).dispose();
                }
            });
        }

        protected void setFormEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                comp.setEnabled(enabled);
            }
        }

        protected void loginSuccessful() {
            SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this).dispose();
        }

        protected void loginFailed() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Login failed", "Fail", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            setFormEnabled(true);
        }

        public class LoginWorker extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                boolean login = false;
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                login = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1) == 0 ? false : true;
                return login;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    Boolean login = get();
                    if (login) {
                        loginSuccessful();
                    } else {
                        loginFailed();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    loginFailed();
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    loginFailed();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```