# What is the equivalent of the DialogResult property from WindowsForms in Java SWING's JFrames?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jframe

I'm writing an application in Java using the Java Swing library and am looking for a functionality equivalent to these lines of code from C# using WindowsForms:

```
 MyDialog form = new MyDialog();
 form.showDialog();

 if (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
      doSomething();
```

I haven't been able to find an equivalent functionality for JFrames in Java.

The code I'm working on is the following:

```
 LoginFrame loginFrame = new LoginFrame(CONTROLLER);
 loginFrame.setVisible(true);
```

The previous 2 lines of code launch a log-in window where the user can input his e-mail and password. Said window displays 2 buttons: OK and CANCEL. After the window has closed, I'm interested in knowing which one of the 2 buttons the user has pressed.

What is the standard way of doing this in Java Swing with JFrames?

Comment: Probably `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(..);`.

Comment: My initial conclusion is that my choice of the JFrame object for dialogs in wrong... can you confirm? Should I be using JDialogs instead? Thanks!

Comment: *"Should I be using JDialogs instead?"* Absolutely, for this, either a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` (which is modal by default). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47644458/418556) for a self contained example of a log-in using a `JOptionPane`. See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) (Typically only the main app. should be based on a `JFrame`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can set [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to your buttons. There's many ways.

**Anonymous Action Listener**

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(e.getSource() == button1) {
            //if clicks the first button
        } else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            //if clicks the second button
        }
    }
});
```

**Class that implements Action Listener** (best option for maintenance issues)

```
class CheckButtonActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(e.getSource() == button1) {
            //if clicks the first button
        } else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            //if clicks the second button
        }
    }

}
```

and, set the class to your JButton:

```
CheckButtonActionListener checker = new CheckButtonActionListener();
button.addActionListener(checker);
```

or:

```
button1.addActionListener(new CheckButtonActionListener();
```

Answer (score 1):

An application will have a single JFrame as the main window.

If you need child window you would use a JDialog. A JDialog is like a JFrame. You need to code all the logic and handle all the button events yourself

A `JOptionPane` is a pre-packaged `JDialog` that give you some default functionality.

You can create a simple JOptionPane with multiple input fields with code something like:

```
JTextField firstName = new JTextField(10);
//firstName.addAncestorListener( new RequestFocusListener() );
JTextField lastName = new JTextField(10);
Object[] msg = {"First Name:", firstName, "Last Name:", lastName};


int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
    frame,
    msg,
    "Enter Name",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    System.out.println(firstName.getText() + " : " + lastName.getText());
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Canceled");
}
```

One problem with the above is that focus will be on the buttons, not the text field. You can fix this problem by using the [Request Focus Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/)

If you don't like the layout of the components in the option pane then you will need to create a custom panel with your components and add the panel to the OptionPane.

You should also check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Making Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). This section and the tutorial is general will give you Swing basics as your transition from C#.